# inline condition for check_box_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to toggle the disabled attribute of a checkbox by checking the params, so something like

```
check_box_tag 'eula', 'accepted', false, disabled: true if params[:true]
```

I could put the whole thing in an if statement, but that seems like overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `params[:true]` is truthy when you want the checkbox to be disabled and falsey when you don't, then all you need to do is this:

```
check_box_tag 'eula', 'accepted', false, 
  disabled: params[:true]
```

Comment: thanks!  I suppose my weary brain missed the obvious solution.  It hit me this morning in the shower how obvious the answer is.